# Two-way binding in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a question about two-way binding in Angular2

I have looked through a lot of examples how to use it with input fields and so on.
But I wanted to try it in my case: I have two components, one of them is shared (reusable) component. Another one has it's own model.

Can I pass a model of the main component to a reusable one and use two-way binding?

```
<day [(currentDay)]="model.currentDay"></day>
```

My questions:

1) Can I do that? Is it in a right way or it's better to use eventEmitter?

2) This is how I store model in main component:

```
model: DayModel = new DayModel(null, null);
```

and here is that model in that reusable component:

```
@Input() currentDay: DayModel;
```

When I'm trying to use it in reusable component and get access to the currentDay, I have such a problem:
"Cannot set property '#someProperty' of undefined" (currentDay is undefined) 
and that's why I need to this:

```
@Input() currentDay: DayOfWeekModel = new DayOfWeekModel(... properties ...);
```

How to avoid it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact with using only @Input, you do half of the job ;-) Only one way binding.

In your case, you also need an @Output with a standardized name:

```
@Output() currentDayChange: EventEmitter<DayModel> = new EventEmitter();
```

To trigger the parent component that there is an update, use this:

```
this.currentDayChange.emit(newValue);
```

The `[(...])` expression is a shortcut for `[...]` plus `(...)`:

```
<day [currentDay]="model.currentDay"
     (currentDayChange)="model.currentDay = $event"></day>
```

So you need to implement both...

Comment: in other way I can't use one @Input() variable for two-way binding ?

Comment: You can use it but you need to work by reference. No primitive value (string, number) will be supported... The approach I described you works in all cases ;-)